# How can I retrieve Meta data from database in Laravel

Tags: laravel, metadata

Here is my database:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG8Hj.jpg)

after dd($product->getMeta(udf)) i got this:
"a:2:{s:4:"Type";s:4:"100w";s:5:"Frame";s:7:"Plastic";}"

My ProductController is like this:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::latest()->with('category', 'supplier')->get();
        return view('admin.product.index', compact('products'));
    }
```

I want to show the data like:
Type: 100w
Frame: Plastic

Comment: What is your `getMeta()` function?

Comment: That's serialized data produced with PHPs [`serialize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) that is generally a recipe for bad database design. You should use relationships via database tables instead

Answer (score 0):

u need to use json_decode() in ur code should something like

```
$jsonMetaData = $product->getMeta(udf);
$metaDataArr = json_decode($jsonMetaData);
print_r($metaDataArr);
```

this will print ur data in array form and u can use / pass this data further